# How to retrieve variable in def __init__ in Python

Tags: python, variables

I need to retrieve a variable inside the `def __init__`. The code as below:

```
class HuffmanCode(object):

    def __init__(self, probabilities, digits):
        self.probabilities = probabilities
        #print (self.probabilities)
        self.huffman = huffman_nary_dict(probabilities, digits)
        #print (self.huffman)
        self.inv_huffman = inverse_dict(self.huffman)
```

I need to call `self.inv_huffman` outside the `class HuffmanCode`. `self.inv_huffman` is a set of dictionary for the specific character that I need to retrieve.

```
self.inv_huffman = {'m': '110', 'a': '0', 's': '10', 'y': '111'}
```

Comment: Um.  Why?  What possible value is there in this global `d`?

Comment: Just access `huffnam_code_instance.inv_huffman`, where `huffnam_code_instance = HuffmanCode(...)`. Why do you need `global`? Using global is frown-upon practice anyway.

Comment: Actually, the original code is without global `d`. I will remove it in the question.

Comment: So you removed a few lines of code.  But now it makes even less sense.  What is `inverse_dict`?  What does it mean to *call* `self.inv_huffman`?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I guess OP asks how to access instance attribute from outside of the method, no?

Comment: @Reblochon Masque. I need to retrieve `self.inv_huffman` outside the HuffmanCode class.

Comment: @Roman Susi. Yes. Exactly.

Comment: This is Python.  You can access anything you want.  While it might not be a good idea, you can do : `x = huffman_code_instance.inv_huffman['m']`. But this is still not really a question.

Comment: So now you have accepted an an answer.  But, what is the question?

Comment: @Stephen Rauch `huffnam_code_instance.inv_huffman` can be used to retrieve `self.inv_huffman ` outside the function.

Comment: Yes it can.  Is that the question?

Comment: @Stephen Rauch. Actually, the question is how to retrieve `self.inv_huffman` outside the function. That's all.

Comment: There is way more text in the question than that. `self` is just a name, that happens to refer to an object.  Whoever instantiated the object also has a name for that object.  It is the same object.  Use the `.` to access an attribute.   And you can do anything you want.  What is to the left of the dot does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost always bad idea to use `global`.

Just access `huffnam_code_instance.inv_huffman`, where `huffnam_code_instance = HuffmanCode(...)`.

Here `huffnam_code_instance` is an instance of the class `HuffmanCode`. Classes are usually there to create instance objects, which are then used in computations. See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

The `self` variable in the methods, including `__init__` points to the instance of the class. In  Python, instance attributes such as `inv_huffman` are public, so in this case it is ok to just use attribute access.

NB, given only a class it is not logical (and very very hard) to access the `self.inv_huffman` value, because it's an instance attribute, and not say class attribute.

Comment: Is this an answer?